# why is a file associated with an object?

Tags: java

Here is a saying in my java school learning notes relating to java text files:
File is a stream of bytes associated with an object

and what I have already got is:
1.Java views a file as a stream of bytes
2.The use of objects allows designers to create programs that are more easily maintained and extended.(http://javadevwannabe.blogspot.hk/2012/02/state-behavior-and-identity.html)
3.An object consist of state and related behavior.
4.object vs class vs method
etc.

But,how should I understand the sentence above and what does "associated with an object" mean here?

THX

Comment: So are we supposed to understand notes *you* wrote which even you don't understand?

Comment: forgot to mention that the note is from my school..

Comment: It's the other way around. There are many Java objects that can represent (aka "be associated with") a file on the file system, e.g. [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html), [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Comment: Only two of the previously mentioned objects view the file as a "stream" of bytes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A file on your machine is associated with a `File` object in Java. This allows the "stream of bytes" to have behaviors (methods) that can be useful for developers.

If I had just a stream of bytes, I can do little more than read the stream and do something with the data of the file. However, with a `File` object, I can do a lot more, including (but certainly not limited to):

- Read metadata about the file (such as `lastModified`)
- `compareTo` another `File` or see if two of them are `equal`
- `getAbsolutePath` of the file for reference

You can read about the functionality of `File` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Finally, treating a file as an object falls in line with object-oriented design. Knowing that a file has a state and behaviors allows it to interact with other objects in the program to achieve a task.

Java attempts to be a purely object-oriented language, and so just about every concept can be in some way formed as an object.

Comment: The Java `File` objects represents a path to a file, and can be used to obtain metadata about the file, but it does not have anything to do with the "stream of bytes" inside the file. `FileInputStream` is the object that does that, and the `File` object doesn't have any method for creating a `FileInputStream`. --- Also, `compareTo` will compare the path (file name), not the file content.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, I didn't mean to imply otherwise.

Comment: Conclusively, can I say that the sentence is trying to say that a file is associated with an file object that associated with other objects?

Comment: And thanks for Andreas,Zircon as only you two didn't oppose my question and had answered everything I expected to hear.